# What is the spring java config equivalent of <context:spring-configured/>?

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

How do I define `<context:spring-configured/>` in Spring java config?

I am currently using `@ImportResource` with an XML context that has only this as a workaround, but it would be nice if this could be done in Java config as well.

Comment: have you tried `@EnableSpringConfigured`??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to docs in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html

```
@Configuration
@EnableSpringConfigured
public class AppConfig {

}
```

Is the substitute of: `<context:spring-configured/>`

Comment: Don't know how I missed that! Thx!